# Date time conversion in extJS or sencha

Tags: extjs

hello there's I want to convert  **03-04-2017 12:00AM to 2017-12-01 12:00:00**
how can I do it in Ext Js 
currently my code is:

```
 this.ToDatePicker = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        fieldLabel: 'Date Time',
        value: Ext.Date.format(new Date(), "d-m-Y h:iA"),
        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            afterrender: function (c) {
                c.getEl().on('click', function (e) {
                    console.log(e.target)
                    NewCssCal_DisableAfterToday(Ext.get(e.target).dom.id, 'ddmmyyyy', 'dropdown', true, 12)
                });
            }
        }
    });

this.ToCalenderIcon = new Ext.Container({
        html: "<img class='calIcons' src='public/touchWorldCssJs/images/cal.gif'/>",
        scope: this,
        padding: '27 5 5 5',
        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            afterrender: function (c) {
                c.getEl().on('click', function (e) {
                    if (Ext.get(e.target).hasCls('calIcons')) {
                        console.log(Ext.get(e.target).dom.id);
                        NewCssCal_DisableAfterToday(me.ToDatePicker.inputEl.id, 'ddmmyyyy', 'dropdown', true, 12)
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

**this.ToCalenderIcon** after rendering this set date formate like **03-04-2017 12:00AM** So I need to convert this to 2017-12-01 12:00:00

Comment: I am not getting your question. You want to convert today's date to  "2017-12-01 12:00:00" format or what you have given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AM/PM notion isn't supported by JavaScript natively as far as I could tell, so you'll have to do the parsing according to the specified format through Ext.Date.

In your toDatePicker, you explicitly format the date to be "d-m-Y h:iA".
To get that back into a different format you need to first parse it (as JavaScript's native Date can't parse the resulting string):

```
Ext.Date.format(Ext.Date.parse("03-04-2017 12:00AM", "d-m-Y h:iA"), "d-m-Y h:i:s")
```

I hope that's what you were looking for.
If you're instead interested how to make the 3rd of April look like the first of December, you should just write 1st of December in the first place.